# Which method to override in android fragment to populate a listview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, overriding

I have an activity which holds the fragment A and Fragment A hold a list view and button, when I pressed the button it directs to another fragment B.

My question is which method I need to override in fragment A so when I pressed the back button, I can re-populate the list view inside. Or is there another simple way I can make it ?

Until now I tried to override the onResume and onStart, it didnt work. Btw I cant override the back button pressed in Fragment B because in that case I cant reach ui components in fragment B and getting a null pointer normally.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if you want to referesh/update listview use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

Your will get NO notice when the previous fragment is show again.
But you can override the onBackPressed() method of the fragment's parent activity like this:

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
     //1.find your fragment A by tag, this tag is supplied 
     //when you using FragmentTransaction.add(int id, Fragment fragment, String tag) 
     //the you can find fragment by this way 
     //FragmentA fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(name)
     //2.call some method of it!
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for being clarifying about I will not get a notice when previous fragment showed again.

My problem is the fragment A is added as a tab to my supportActionBar so I cant get Fragment A by using findFragmentByTag method.

Comment: hmm, i am confused about your problem? Do you want to do something when the "back key" is pressed? What do you want to to?